# I entered the code, I need to recognize and remove a certain word from the screenshot

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-tesseract

need to be deleted en masse, let's say in my case the word©pomogalka.me from the screenshot, I tried everything, no, it doesn’t delete.
uploaded a photo screenshot with an example, please help me, good people
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03598.jpg)
The code itself

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk
import cv2
import pytesseract
import re

# Set the path to the Tesseract OCR executable
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 lang=eng'

def remove_text(input_folder, output_folder, text_to_remove, progress_var):
    images = os.listdir(input_folder)
    total_images = len(images)
    progress_step = 100 / total_images
    current_progress = 0

    for image_name in images:
        image_path = os.path.join(input_folder, image_name)
        output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, image_name)
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)

        if image is None:
            messagebox.showwarning("Warning", f"Failed to read image {image_name}")
            continue

        # Preprocess the image
        processed_image = preprocess_image(image)

        # Convert the image to text using pytesseract
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(processed_image, config=custom_config)

        # Remove all occurrences of the specified word from the text using regular expressions
        modified_text = re.sub(r'\b' + re.escape(text_to_remove) + r'\b', '', text)

        # Convert back to image
        modified_image = image.copy()
        cv2.putText(modified_image, modified_text, (10, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)

        # Save the processed image
        cv2.imwrite(output_path, modified_image)

        current_progress += progress_step
        progress_var.set(current_progress)

def preprocess_image(image):
    # Apply blurring
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)
    return blurred

def select_input_folder():
    input_folder = filedialog.askdirectory()
    input_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    input_entry.insert(0, input_folder)

def select_output_folder():
    output_folder = filedialog.askdirectory()
    output_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    output_entry.insert(0, output_folder)

def process_images():
    input_folder = input_entry.get()
    output_folder = output_entry.get()
    text_to_remove = text_entry.get()

    if not input_folder or not output_folder:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please select input and output folders.")
        return

    progress_var.set(0)

    remove_text(input_folder, output_folder, text_to_remove, progress_var)

    messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Images processed successfully.")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Image Text Remover")

frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="20")
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E, tk.N, tk.S))

input_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Input Folder:")
input_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

input_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=50)
input_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

input_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Browse", command=select_input_folder)
input_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

output_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Output Folder:")
output_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

output_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=50)
output_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

output_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Browse", command=select_output_folder)
output_button.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

text_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="Text to Remove:")
text_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

text_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=50)
text_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

process_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Process Images", command=process_images)
process_button.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=10)

progress_var = tk.DoubleVar()
progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate', variable=progress_var)
progress_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to gea screenshot of the word at the exit ©pomogalka.me

Comment: You can use cv2.grabcut or inpaint.